# how to disable dropdown options based on the previously selected dropdown values in multi select dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, sumoselect.js

i am having two multi select dropdowns. those two dropdowns will have the same set of options (like monday, tuesday ,wednesday). now i want to have a validation where in one dropdown of these selected to some options(these are multi select dropdowns.), then the same options should not be available to select from the other dropdown.(means those should be disable.) here for multi select i am using one UI js plugin [multi select dropdown javascript plugin](http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/sumoselect_demo.html).

```
<label for="shift_day_list_1">Day</label> 
      <input name="shift[day_list_1][]" type="hidden" value="" /><select class="form-control" id="day_list_1" multiple="multiple" name="shift[day_list_1][]"><option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
<option value="Monday">Monday</option>
<option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
<option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
<option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
<option value="Friday">Friday</option>
<option value="Saturday">Saturday</option></select>

<label for="shift_day_list_2">Day</label> 
      <input name="shift[day_list_2][]" type="hidden" value="" /><select class="form-control" id="day_list_2" multiple="multiple" name="shift[day_list_2][]"><option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
<option value="Monday">Monday</option>
<option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
<option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
<option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
<option value="Friday">Friday</option>
<option value="Saturday">Saturday</option></select>
```

this is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#day_list_1').SumoSelect({
      placeholder: 'Select Days',
      csvDispCount: 3 
      });

      $('#day_list_2').SumoSelect({
      placeholder: 'Select Days',
      csvDispCount: 3 
      });
 });
```

how to implement this? please help me?

Comment: i see same ID , ID should be unique all the time

Comment: Where ia your js/jquery code?

Comment: try this document.getElementById("day_list_2").options[document.getElementById("day_list_1").selectedIndex].disabled = true;

Comment: and Id should be different for select tag! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a full commented snippet for you:

```js
// when all the elements in the DOM are loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {  
  // get both lists and their HTMLOptionElement nodes
  var list1 = document.getElementById('day_list_1'),
      list2 = document.getElementById('day_list_2'),
      options1 = list1.querySelectorAll('option'),
      options2 = list2.querySelectorAll('option');
  
  // add event handlers when the lists are changed to call the update function
  $(list1).change(update).SumoSelect();
  $(list2).change(update).SumoSelect();

  function update(e) {
    // when the lists are changed, loop through their HTMLOptionElement nodes
    var other = (list1 === this) ? list2 : list1;    
    for (var i = 0; i < options1.length; i++) {
      // options of list1 should be disabled if selected in list2 and vice-versa
      this[i].selected ? other.sumo.disableItem(i) : other[i].selected ? void 0 : other.sumo.enableItem(i);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.form-control {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/stylesheets/sumoselect.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/javascripts/jquery.sumoselect.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" id="day_list_1" multiple="multiple" name="shift[day_list_1][]">
  <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
  <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
  <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
  <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
  <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="day_list_2" multiple="multiple" name="shift[day_list_2][]">
  <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
  <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
  <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
  <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
  <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
</select>
```

Comment: iam using a plugin for this. http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/.  for good UI. how can i use these plugin options to achieve this? that i am unable to figure it out.

Comment: They have method like `.disableItem(index)`, **Read the documentation**

Comment: any idea how can I make it work with `n` number of SumoSelect boxes? @Buzinas

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this jsfiddle
[Click here for jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pd5Nk/1/)

```
$("#theSelect option[value=" + value + "]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

But before this, you need to add change event to the first select/dropdownlist. I hope you can take from here..

Comment: fiddle link is not opening.

Comment: Updated the proper link

Comment: iam using a plugin for this. http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/ . for good UI. how can i use these plugin options to achieve this? that i am unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

you can use normal js to achieve this.Use this following code on day_list_‌​1 on onChange event.

`document.getElementById("day_list_2").options[document.getElementById("day_list_‌​1").selectedIndex].disabled = true;`

Comment: iam using a plugin for this. http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/  .for good UI. how can i use these plugin options to achieve this? that i am unable to figure it out.

Comment: it seems sumoselect has similar options to it $('select.SlectBox')[0].sumo.disableItem(2);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('#day_list_1').on('change', function() {
  $('#day_list_2').find('option').removeProp('disabled');
  var val = $(this).val() || [];
  val.forEach(function(item) {
    $('#day_list_2').find('[value=' + item + ']').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});
$('#day_list_2').on('change', function() {
  $('#day_list_1').find('option').removeProp('disabled');
  var val = $(this).val() || [];
  val.forEach(function(item) {
    $('#day_list_1').find('[value=' + item + ']').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="day_list_1">Day</label>
<input type="hidden" value="" />
<select class="form-control" id="day_list_1" multiple="multiple" name="shift[day_list_1][]">
  <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
  <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
  <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
  <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
  <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
</select>


<label for="day_list_2">Day</label>
<input type="hidden" value="" />
<select class="form-control" id="day_list_2" multiple="multiple" name="shift[day_list_1][]">
  <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
  <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
  <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
  <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
  <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
</select>
```

Comment: iam using a plugin for this. http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/ .for good UI. how can i use these plugin options to achieve this? that i am unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to change the id of "day_list_1", because as per HTML standard there is only one id in the entire HTML of any tag.

So you should do like this :

First one :

```
<select class="form-control" id="day_list_1" multiple="multiple" 
name="shift[day_list_1][]">
```

Next one:

```
<select class="form-control" id="day_list_2" multiple="multiple" name="shift[day_list_1][]">
```

Code for validation :

```
function validate(){

  var error = false;
  var selected_val_1 = []; 
  $('#day_list_1 :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
    selected_val_1[i] = $(selected).text(); 
  });

  var selected_val_2 = []; 
  $('#day_list_2 :selected').each(function(i, selected){ 
    selected_val_2[i] = $(selected).text(); 
  });

  $.each(selected_val_1, function( index, value ) {
              if($.inArray(value, selected_val_2) != -1){
                    error = true;
              }
  });

  $.each(selected_val_2, function( index, value ) {
              if($.inArray(value, selected_val_1) != -1){
                    error = true;
              }
  });

  if(error == true){
     return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }

}
```

I hope it helps you . If you have any query regarding this logic then you can revert me .

Thanks.

Comment: iam using a plugin for this.  http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/ .for good UI. how can i use these plugin options to achieve this? that i am unable to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks John , for info about your code . You can use this for getting value instead of my previous code : 
$('.select1 option:selected').each(function(){ //your selected values });
By this you can get array of selected values and after that you can validate the values as per your conditions and disable that value.

Answer (score 0):

It will work fine for 3 drop downs also

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).load(function(){
        var $dropdown1 = $("select[name='project_manager[]']");
        var $dropdown2 = $("select[name='test_engineer[]']");
        var $dropdown3 = $("select[name='viewer[]']");

        $dropdown1.change(function() {
            $dropdown2.empty().append($dropdown1.find('option').clone());
            $dropdown3.empty().append($dropdown2.find('option').clone());
            var selectedItem = $(this).val();
            if (selectedItem) {
                $(selectedItem).each(function(v,selectedItem) {
                $dropdown2.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
                $dropdown3.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
             });
            }
        });

        $dropdown2.change(function() {
            $dropdown3.empty().append($dropdown2.find('option').clone());
            var selectedItem = $(this).val();
            if (selectedItem) {
                $(selectedItem).each(function(v,selectedItem) {
                    $dropdown3.find('option[value="' + selectedItem + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
                });
            }
        });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="project_manager" name="project_manager[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option></option>
  <option  id="option" value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option id="option" value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option  id="option" value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>

<select id="test_engineer" name="test_engineer[]" multiple="multiple" >
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
<select name="viewer[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
  <script>
    // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
    if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
      window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
        height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
        slug: "vrLr9wyg"
      }], "*")
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```